# Unit testing with RestClient - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing

I'd like to add unit tests for an HTTP call, using `RestClient`

I've read a bit and seems like I can use `@RestClientTest` but that seems to be for integration tests (it starts the server).

https://www.baeldung.com/restclienttest-in-spring-boot

With `restTemplate` I can do this.

```
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

private void setRestTemplateResponse(MyResponse response) {
  given(restTemplate.getForObject(
                "my-endpoint", MyRespose.class
        )).willReturn(response);
    }
```

So I was looking for a similar way to do it. Tried this but got a `NullPointerException` because `restClient.get()` is a method that comes from an interface

```
@Mock
private RestClient restClient;

private void setRestTemplateResponse(MyResponse response) {
   given(restClient.get().uri("my-endpoint"
        ).retrieve().body(MyResponse.class)).willReturn(response);
    }
```

---

EDIT #1

Added:

```
@Autowired
private RestClient restClient;
@BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        this.restClient = RestClient.builder().build();
        adapter = new MyServiceImpl(BASE_URL, restClient);
    }
```

I'm not getting the exception, but now, it's actually making the request towards to endpoint which obviously fails

Comment: looking at your provided tutorial, i see that the clients should be annotated with `@Autowired` - but you use `@Mock` ... that somehow puzzles me. And that would explain why `@Mock RestClient restClient.get()` returns `null`...

Comment: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.client.RestClient.get()" because "this.restClient" is null.

Do I need to instanciate a restClient object? could you give an example?
I tried with @InjectMock but since RestClient is an interface it can't inject it

Comment: @MartinFrank using autowired will make the request, it doesn't mock it at all

Comment: sorry for my late response, i do not really understand the purpose of your question, sorry....